# do not show function help document in building R package by roxygen2

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am using `devtools` to build R package, and there are some functions that are NOT designed to be visible to end-users. However, since these functions involve calling C codes by `.Call`, so that I have to write `@useDynLib` above the function for automatic generation of .Rd files. In that way, when I build the package, even I did NOT include the `@export` for those functions, they nonetheless appear in the help document... Is there a way to **suppress** those functions even if they have been documented? Thanks!

Comment: You only need one `useDynLib` declaration per package.

Comment: @hadley: thanks, I've corrected that...but still functions without `@ export` are in the help document, which I wish are invisible to end-users. Any method to "suppress" producing .Rd files?

Comment: Don't use roxygen comments?

Comment: @hadley: I think in order to automatically update the NAMESPACE to include `@ useDynLib` I prefer to use roxygen2... Just curious how can I make the functions invisible to end-users (even if they have associated .Rd) Thanks ;-)

Comment: Oh then you want `@keywords internal`

Comment: @hadley: thank you so much! that works perfectly -- I should read through your wiki pages on devtools as you wrote explicitly there ;-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to Hadley's comments, use `@keywords internal` will make the function invisible to end-users. Details can be found [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html) in the wiki pages of `devtools`.

Answer (score 12):

The wiki linked in the accepted answer no longer discusses `@keywords internal` (as of April 2016). In case it's helpful for someone to see an example:

```
# multiplyBy3
#' This is an example of an internal function called \code{multiplyBy3()}
#'
#' Sometimes you want internal functions as part of an R Package built with 
#' RStudio and roxygen2, but you don't want .Rd files created for them
#' or to have them be visible in the help document following the build process
#' 
#' @keywords internal
#'
#' @param base_num The number to multiply by three 
#'
#' @import jsonlite
#'
#' @return Returns a numeric vector
#'
multiplyBy3 <- function(base_number) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(base_number))
  return(base_number * 3)
}
```

Key bits: do not include `@export` and do include `@keywords internal`

Comment: This is what I was searching for the past half an hour. Thanks @arvi1000

Answer (score 10):

For me, `@keywords internal` did not work (roxygen2 6.1.1). I was able to achieve the desired result using the following in my roxygen comments:

```
@noRd
```

Comment: see https://community.rstudio.com/t/keywords-internal-vs-nord/35119 for a discussion of the differences between these: `"@keywords internal is useful because it removes the function from the documentation index."` whereas `"@NoRd means there won't even be a manual page so the roxygen2 doc of that function only lives in the R script"`