# Need to document arguments in functions which are not exported in R package?

Tags: r, devtools

I am using the `devtools` package to check if a package I am developing is ready for submission to CRAN.

Using `Roxygen2` through `devtools`, I documented a small number of functions with `#'@export`, in order for them to be available when the package I am developing is loaded.

However, when I run `devtools::check()`, it  seems I need to document the functions that are NOT exported, i.e. those that may be called by a function which is exported, but which are not available nor needed by whoever uses the package. Here is an example from the output of `devtools::check()`:

```
checking Rd \usage sections ... WARNING
Undocumented arguments in documentation object 'calculate_agreement'
  ‘a_assign_star’ ‘a_assign’
```

Do I need to document those arguments although the function is not exported?

Comment: You need to document all arguments to exported functions. This message occurs when you have exported a function but not described all of its arguments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the problem here (based on past experience) is that you are probably using Roxygen comment delimiters `#'` in the preamble to the function. This (I'm pretty sure) triggers the creation of a `.Rd` file (and the need to document parameters), whether or not you have an `@export` directive or not. My solution in this case was to use regular `#` commenting rather than `#'`.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892761/do-not-show-function-help-document-in-building-r-package-by-roxygen2?rq=1) it's possible that an explicit `@keywords internal` directive would also work (but I haven't tried it).

@mattb points out that specifying `@noRd` [should also work](https://community.rstudio.com/t/keywords-internal-vs-nord/35119).

Comment: So is it considered bad practice to document (with Roxygen I mean) non-exported  functions ? It makes them appear in the package documentation while they are not available through normal `::` operator, which could be misleading for the user ?

Comment: I think if you use the `@keywords internal` directive, all of the non-exported packages will end up on a single "internal" man page (where you could explain why they're there ...?

Comment: Also see `@noRd` which [means there won't even be a manual page so the roxygen2 doc of that function only lives in the R script](https://community.rstudio.com/t/keywords-internal-vs-nord/35119)